# Put quoutes around data in csv export from Google Spredsheets

Tags: google-sheets, csv

I have about 200 rows each with 7 columns in Google Spreadsheets which I am exporting to csv, so that I can separate columns by comma and use this data in PHP arrays. 
I get this

```
something, something, 242342, asdffds,
something, something, 242342, asdffds,
something, something, 242342, asdffds,
```

Is there any way I can put `'` around data so that I get this?

```
'something', 'something', '242342', 'asdffds',
'something', 'something', '242342', 'asdffds',
'something', 'something', '242342', 'asdffds',
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new sheet
2. Add the following formula to A1

   ```
   =ArrayFormula("'"&Sheet1!A1:D3&"'")
   ```

   NOTE:Replace `Sheet1!A1:D3` by the proper reference.
3. Download the new sheet to as a CSV file.